# Linked list creates infinte loop when outputted (No Iterators allowed)

Tags: java, list, infinite-loop

When the user stores two or more values into the list, the output displays this:

```
item 3: null
item 4: null
item 5: null
...
item 14623: null
```

This is the case for when the user wants to output the list

```
case OUTPUT:
{
    System.out.println ("The List:");
    displayList();
    break;
}
```

Which leads to the displayList() method

```
public static void displayList()
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= list.size (); i++)
    {
        System.out.println ("item " + i + ": " + list.get(i));
    }
}
```

Which uses list.size()

```
public int size()
{
    for(Node n = header; n.getNext() != null; n = n.getNext())
    {
        size++;
    }
    return size;
}
```

and list.get()

```
public Object get(int index)
{
    Node n = traverse(index);

    if (n == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    return n.getData();
}
```

getNext()

```
public Node getNext()
{
    return next;
}
```

traverse(). I think this method is what's causing the problems

```
public Node traverse(int index)
{
    Node n = header;

    if (index < 0)
    {
        return null;
    }

    for (int indexTwo = 0; indexTwo < index; indexTwo++)
    {
        if (n == null)
        {
            return null;
        } // end of if (n == null)
        n = n.getNext ();
    }
    return n;
}
```

Comment: could you share the code which generates the list in the first place? also the list class that you are using

Comment: Are you initializing the `header`? if Node n = header;
is null, the whole thing will return null

Comment: By that do you mean the method which adds the values to the list? Also we have to make our list clss

Comment: Also, until n is null, you are increasing the size which might also cause issues.

Comment: Try calling the size() method on your list. What does it return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part is never executed:

```
for (int indexTwo = 0; indexTwo < index; indexTwo++)
```

since your `index` variable is `0` and `indexTwo < index` gives `false`.
Use:

```
for (int indexTwo = 0; indexTwo <= index; indexTwo++)
```

Edit:

Another issue is in your `size()` method:

```
public int size()
{
    for(Node n = header; n.getNext() != null; n = n.getNext())
    {
        size++;
    }
    return size;
}
```

where you increment your `size` variable which is a static? one. So, it must have initialized elsewhere. I guess you need to make it a local variable and initialize it inside this method.
Another issue is that you get your `getNext()` twice in each step:

for(Node n = header; **n.getNext**() != null; n = **n.getNext**())

Just check `n` not `n.getNext() != null` for `null`.

Comment: Unfortunately, the output is still an infinite loop